# MongoDB aggregation : get day, month and year from date/timestamp in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This syntax is to find any object "gt" date or between two date with "lt", so I do this:

```
db.compte.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      time: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$auditMessages",
          as: "auditMessages",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $gt: ["$$auditMessages.timestamp", "2020-05-20T07:18:42.115Z"]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

And this is result, it works :

```
{
  _id: ObjectId"5ed638e566a699750cbb1b0f"),
  time: [
    {
      eventCategory: "Audit",
      objectType: "Audit Log",
      eventAction: "Query",
      status: "Initiated",
      username: "Unknown",
      userId: "Unknown",
      timestamp: "2020-05-20T07:19:05.149Z",
      eventDescription: "Querying without filters."
    },
    {
      eventCategory: "Audit",
      objectType: "Audit Log",
      eventAction: "Query",
      status: "Successful",
      username: "Unknown",
      userId: "Unknown",
      timestamp: "2020-05-20T07:18:42.232Z",
      eventDescription: "Querying without filters."
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to find day, month and year for example I want timestamp like this:
year:2020
month: 05
day: 20
hour:07
minute:18 and millisecond: 42

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is aggregation operator [$dateToParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToParts/index.html#datetoparts-aggregation) :

As your date field i.e; `timestamp` is in an array we're iterating over using `$map` & merging all the fields `year`, `month`, `hour`, `minute` etc.. to actual object and pushing back the object to `time` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      time: {
        $map: {
          input: "$time",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $dateToParts: {
                  date: "$$this.timestamp"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NDP9JGFf07Y)

**Note :**

Just in case if your `timestamp` field is a string then you need to convert it into date using [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/index.html#datefromstring-aggregation) operator. Check this : [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nqo2wD0Nb7r)

**Change will be here :**

```
 {
    $dateToParts: {
         date: {
           $dateFromString: {
               dateString: "$$this.timestamp"
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: can you please, give me the all syntax I test it and it doens't work for me and the type of timestamp is string

Comment: @m1h3r : what do you mean by all syntax & not working ?

Comment: @ whoami I test this db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      time: {
        $map: {
          input: "$time",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $dateToParts: {date: "$$this.timestamp" } } ]} } } }}]) but it doens't work

Comment: @m1h3r : As I've already said for date in string format you need to use the second one !! Check the playground link in **Note**

Comment: the same result when I test it in Robo 3T, doesn't work

Comment: @m1h3r : It should give you an error atleast !! what do you mean by **doesn't work** ? what's happening ? You need to say that unless you explain it I can't help anymore !! As this works perfectly in playground..